# Problem with headjs resizer

Tags: javascript, head.js

I have been playing around lately with head.js but I have found a stranger behavior that I think is not normal. When I'm using the screen size detector for resizing functionality the classes for the size doesn't change as it was expected to adapt to the new size (when you change the size of the window).

Have anyone experienced a similar problem with head.js?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Head.js answered the ticket on Github and the problem is fixed:

> This is now fixed:
>
> https://github.com/headjs/headjs/commit/91324d8e676fd7a7f22c9f51f5482db0cb155f1b
>
> NOTE: I did not update the minified
>   version of the file at this point.
>
> Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around on the headjs.com website, it doesn't seem as if its updating the classes as I resize my browser (which it is supposed to do according to the description).  Perhaps a bug report is in order?

Comment: It is supposed that you declare some classes depending on your screen sizes an then de head.js script change the classes based on the real windows size, and choose the more appropriated, but is not working, the classes never change.

Comment: Yea.  headjs adds classes to the html tag based on your window size upon loading the page.  According to the script's description, it is supposed to alter those classes dynamically as you resize the page, but its not doing so (at least in FF).  I think you should hop on his Github and submit a bug report.